# Azure Logic App (Consumption) and Azure Service Bus Connector-The operation cannot be performed because the entity has been closed or aborted

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I have configured the Azure Logic App with a Service Bus Queue Trigger (when one or more messages arrive in a queue (peek-lock)). Inside this logic app, I used the "Renew lock on the message in a queue" action before this "Complete the message in a queue" action to delete the message from the queue after it was successfully processed.

The above logic app flow has been working fine for a few months, but suddenly the logic app is failing with this error: "**The operation cannot be performed because the entity has been closed or aborted.**" while deleting the message from the queue.

> {
> "status": 400,
> "message": "The operation cannot be performed because the entity has been closed or aborted.\r\nclientRequestId: xxxxxxxxxxx",
> "error": {
> "message": "The operation cannot be performed because the entity has been closed or aborted."
> },
> "source": "sxxxxxxxxx"
> }

After troubleshooting, I restarted the logic app, and then it was working fine.

So, can anyone suggest why the above error occurred suddenly?

Answer (score 0):

> { “status”: 400, “message”: “The operation cannot be performed because
> the entity has been closed or aborted.\r\nclientRequestId:
> xxxxxxxxxxx”, “error”: { “message”: “The operation cannot be performed
> because the entity has been closed or aborted.” }, “source”:
> “sxxxxxxxxx” }

I deployed Azure Service bus and connected Logic apps with Azure Service Bus Connector like below:-

[image]

> This error occurs when the Service Bus operation is invoked on an
> operation that is canceled or aborted or disposed of. This is an
> occurrence of
> OperationCanceledException
> in Azure Service Bus messaging exception.

If you want to get more insights on the error, You can use Diagnostics settings at the left of your Azure Service Bus instance and send the Logs to Log Analytics Workspace or Storage account and query like below:-

[image]

**References :-**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions

Github- https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/31 By Sean Feldman